# USB hub not working properly Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, usb, power-management, external-hdd, usb-modem

USB hub acting strange on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

On Windows all devices are working properly, but on Ubuntu there are several issues, so it is not hardware issue.

1. HDD is not recognised, unless it is the only device attached to hub. Otherwise it switches off after 1 sec, restarts, switches off - infinite loop.
2. Adding and removing Modem restarts rest of devices.
3. When any of the devices are working with full performance, mouse signal becomes really week and sometimes lags.

**What kind of daemon has possessed my Ubuntu 12.04?**

---

UPDATE:

[Link to Trust website USB HUB model](http://trust.com/products/product.aspx?artnr=15005)

**Scheme:**
Samsung laptop 
<- USB2 wire 
<- USB HUB 
<- Phone,HDD,4G Modem, Mouse receiver.

**Output of *lsusb -v -t***

```
2-1.2.1:1.3: No such file or directory
2-1.2.2:1.2: No such file or directory
2-1.2.2:1.4: No such file or directory
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/8p, 480M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 3, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 1, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 2, Class=vend., Driver=option, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 3, Class=vend., Driver=, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 4, Class=stor., Driver=usb-storage, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 5, Class=stor., Driver=usb-storage, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 0, Class=comm., Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 1, Class=data, Driver=cdc_acm, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 2, Class=vend., Driver=, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 3, Class=stor., Driver=usb-storage, 480M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 8, If 4, Class=vend., Driver=, 480M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 0, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 5, If 1, Class=HID, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=ehci_hcd/3p, 480M
    |__ Port 1: Dev 2, If 0, Class=hub, Driver=hub/6p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 0, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 3, If 1, Class='bInterfaceClass 0x0e not yet handled', Driver=uvcvideo, 480M
```

**Output of *lsmod***

```
Module                  Size  Used by
ppp_deflate            13038  0 
zlib_deflate           27139  1 ppp_deflate
bsd_comp               12994  0 
ppp_async              17539  0 
crc_ccitt              12667  1 ppp_async
vesafb                 13844  1 
xt_limit               12711  8 
xt_tcpudp              12603  7 
ipt_LOG                12919  8 
ipt_MASQUERADE         12759  0 
xt_DSCP                12629  0 
ipt_REJECT             12576  1 
nf_conntrack_irc       13383  0 
nf_conntrack_ftp       13452  0 
xt_state               12578  6 
rfcomm                 47604  0 
bnep                   18281  2 
bluetooth             180104  10 rfcomm,bnep
parport_pc             32866  0 
binfmt_misc            17540  1 
ppdev                  17113  0 
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     32474  4 
snd_hda_codec_realtek   224066  1 
cdc_acm                26858  0 
snd_hda_intel          33773  5 
snd_hda_codec         127706  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              13668  1 snd_hda_codec
arc4                   12529  2 
snd_pcm                97188  3 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec
ath9k                 132390  0 
mac80211              506816  1 ath9k
nvidia              12319264  53 
snd_seq_midi           13324  0 
joydev                 17693  0 
snd_rawmidi            30748  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq_midi_event     14899  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_seq                61896  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
ath9k_common           14053  1 ath9k
ath9k_hw              411151  2 ath9k,ath9k_common
psmouse                87692  0 
lp                     17799  0 
option                 25932  0 
usb_wwan               20491  1 option
usbserial              47077  2 option,usb_wwan
uvcvideo               72627  0 
videodev               98259  1 uvcvideo
v4l2_compat_ioctl32    17128  1 videodev
video                  19596  0 
iptable_nat            13229  0 
snd_timer              29990  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd_seq_device         14540  3 snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq
nf_nat                 25891  2 ipt_MASQUERADE,iptable_nat
nf_conntrack_ipv4      19716  9 iptable_nat,nf_nat
nf_conntrack           81926  7 ipt_MASQUERADE,nf_conntrack_irc,nf_conntrack_ftp,xt_state,iptable_nat,nf_nat,nf_conntrack_ipv4
ath                    24067  3 ath9k,ath9k_common,ath9k_hw
serio_raw              13211  0 
mac_hid                13253  0 
snd                    78855  20 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hwdep,snd_pcm,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq,snd_timer,snd_seq_device
nf_defrag_ipv4         12729  1 nf_conntrack_ipv4
parport                46562  3 parport_pc,ppdev,lp
iptable_mangle         12734  0 
soundcore              15091  1 snd
snd_page_alloc         18529  2 snd_hda_intel,snd_pcm
iptable_filter         12810  1 
ip_tables              27473  3 iptable_nat,iptable_mangle,iptable_filter
x_tables               29846  11 xt_limit,xt_tcpudp,ipt_LOG,ipt_MASQUERADE,xt_DSCP,ipt_REJECT,xt_state,iptable_nat,iptable_mangle,iptable_filter,ip_tables
cfg80211              205544  3 ath9k,mac80211,ath
samsung_laptop         14365  0 
usbhid                 47199  0 
hid                    99559  1 usbhid
usb_storage            49198  0 
uas                    18180  0 
sky2                   59043  0
```

**Output of *dmesg***

https://gist.github.com/0ea81d14f47c3a99b5ae

**Output of */var/log/kern.log***

https://gist.github.com/17df3a1517efc72a2a3e

**Output of *lsusb -vvv***

https://gist.github.com/5dc9895df2749f524b2e

Comment: Please also include output of `dmesg`, and `lsmod`, and the exact manufacturer/model number of your USB hub. This sounds like a driver problem.

Comment: Yes, please use this method... Please share the content or output of the following commands/files to better help us troubleshoot your problem [(*instructions in this answer*)](http://askubuntu.com/q/152371/58612): file(s): `/var/log/kern.log`, command(s): `dmesg`

Comment: @izx I updated the answer with link to gist holding the output of dmesg and /var/log/kern.log

Comment: Please pastebin output of `sudo lsusb -vvv` *with all devices connected*. You do realize that this is an unpowered USB hub?

Comment: @izx I have updated OP. Furthermore, I think output of sudo lsusb -vvv is very.. how to call it.. misleading? Not that it's wrong, it just suggests that it is both self powered in some places and that there is no power in others. Cannot get my head around it.

Comment: So you see - all of my devices are self-powered, and none f them need more than ~4,5V, and my computer has 5.0V, so they should all work. They do on Windows, seriously.

Comment: How are all devices self-powered!!?? You have 4 separate power adapters going to the modem, hdd, mouse and phone, along with 4 USB connections to the hub?

Comment: I thought "self-powered" means without AC/DC adapter. My bad :D

Comment: @izx so, did you find anything wrong with my setup? If you didn't - any suggestions?

Comment: Please see answer - I strongly believe this is related to your hub being bus-powered instead of self-powered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

- Your hub appears to be bus-powered (i.e. no AC/DC adapter). The total peak power consumption of all devices connected to it should ideally be limited to 500 mA according to the USB standard.
- The devices you currently have attached probably draw much more than that total, e.g. a 2.5" HDD will easily draw 500 mA on its own; a smart-phone being charged will also max out 500 mA.
- While it may work in Windows, the problem definitely appears to be power here based on your description and the kernel log:

  - Portable HD attempting to start every second is a *guaranteed* sign of not enough power
  - If removing/reattaching one device causes the rest to do the same, then the hub is getting reset, probably because it can't source enough power from the computer to keep itself running along with all the devices.
- *Trust hubs* seem to be [causing problems with Linux/Ubuntu for others too...](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=979829)

My **strong recommendation** at this point is to switch to a *self-powered* hub, i.e. the hub has its own AC/DC adapter. For example, [any of the *Trust* hubs on this page](http://trust.com/products/group.aspx?ProductCategory=CONNECT&ProductGroup=USB-HUBS) which say they include a power adapter or "extra power" should work fine.